# Using a return value from a FileReader's onload function

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using a function in a loop of files to validate each file, I need to go through the lines and match the version.

I've tried using an observable around my whole operation, unfortunately was not able to get it working the right way.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```js
checkDumpVersion(file: File, vcVersion: string): boolean {

  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    let firstLine = reader.result.toString().split(/\r\n|\n/).shift();
    let tokens = firstLine.split(/(\s+)/).filter(e => e.trim().length > 0)
    let version = tokens[tokens.indexOf('VERSION') + 1];

    if (version !== VC_TO_DUMP[vcVersion]) {
      console.log(STATUS['versionValidationError']);
      // need to return false here.
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You can use a callback function to return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `callback` function to return your response

```
checkDumpVersion(file: File, vcVersion: string, callback): boolean{

let reader = new FileReader(); reader.readAsText(file);

reader.onload = function(e){
  let firstLine = reader.result.toString().split(/\r\n|\n/).shift();
  let tokens = firstLine.split(/(\s+)/).filter( e => e.trim().length > 0)
  let version = tokens[tokens.indexOf('VERSION') + 1];

  if(version !== VC_TO_DUMP[vcVersion]){
    console.log(STATUS['versionValidationError']);
    // need to return false here.
    callback(false)
  }
}
return true;
}

checkDumpVersion(file, vcVersion, (data)=> {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: if it isn't executable (ie, pure js, then don't put it in a code snippet)